# React Props: Cannot access GitHub API objects (I'm not that savvy)

Tags: reactjs, api

I'm trying to add cards that shows Github users name, avatar, location and bio. I was able to get the avatar image, name, but whenever I add location to the list, nothing happens even though it is defined. I have spent hours searching, trying different methods but I don't seem to find out the the reason.Any help would be so much appreciated. Here is a snippet of the code, and the complete one is on Github here: https://github.com/aymanxdev/react-github-users-finder

````
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import CardActionArea from "@material-ui/core/CardActionArea";
import CardActions from "@material-ui/core/CardActions";
import CardContent from "@material-ui/core/CardContent";
import CardMedia from "@material-ui/core/CardMedia";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";


const useStyles = makeStyles({

  root: {  
    maxWidth: 345
  },
  media: {
     
    height: 220
  }
});
function UserItem (props){
    const classes = useStyles();

    const { avatar_url, login, location } = props.user;

    return (
     
    <Card className={classes.root}>
      <CardActionArea>
        <CardMedia
          className={classes.media}
          image={avatar_url}
        />
        <CardContent>
          <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
            {login}
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
          {location}
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </CardActionArea>
      <CardActions>
        <Button href={`/users/${login}`} variant="outlined" color="primary">
        Read More
        </Button>
      </CardActions>
    </Card>
    )
}

export default UserItem ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you hit the Github API, it responds with something like below.

```
"items": [
{
  "login": "john",
  "id": 1668,
  "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjE2Njg=",
  "avatar_url": "https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/1668?v=4",
  "gravatar_id": "",
  "url": "https://api.github.com/users/john",
  "html_url": "https://github.com/john",
  "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/john/followers",
  "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/john/following{/other_user}",
  "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/john/gists{/gist_id}",
  "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/john/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
  "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/john/subscriptions",
  "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/john/orgs",
  "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/john/repos",
  "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/john/events{/privacy}",
  "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/john/received_events",
  "type": "User",
  "site_admin": false,
  "score": 1.0
}]
```

As you see, `location` property is not present in response from API, so you can not access it.

GitHub API:

```
https://api.github.com/search/users?q="john"
```

Comment: May I know how did you get the properties of GitHub API when hits, and can I add location to it?

Comment: Do you know how I can access the location from the same endpoint? I can access it from the user page but not the search one. Thank you so much

Comment: After you get the response from search API `https://api.github.com/search/users?q="john"`, you will get the `items` array containing list of users objects from which you have to select `url` property and make the AJAX call. It will respond with user-specific details containing `location`.